# Render only specific item of object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My head got stuck with, i think, some simple problem.

I´m using React with Redux an i have an Array with objects.
Lets say, every Object in this array has two properties. (item a & item b)

So now i´m mapping over this array, render all "itemA".

Now when i click on a specific rendered propertie, i want to display only the "itemB" of the clicked "itemA". I need to display it via createPortal.

I never worked before with Redux and didnt used createPortal for now.

I think it would work with .filter, but i have no clue how to do this with Redux,createPortal?!

So with this code, i render all "itemB" when i click a "itemB"

The event in my handleClick was just for trying around if i can get something out of the event.

P.S. I think the Modal has to be outside of the .map and i have to get the index of the clicked item and search for this index in my modal ?!

```
{products.map(({ itemA,id,itemB }, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p onClick={event => handleListClick(itemA,id,itemB,event)} key={index} id={index}>
              {itemA}
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} displayedItem={itemB}/>
            </p>
          </div>
        )
    })}
```

EDIT:

I got it myself right now!

I made a new state

```
 setClickedItem(products.filter(product => product.id === id))
```

and then i send this new state into the modal :D

Comment: "every Object in this array has two items" makes no sense. Arrays have items. Do you mean object properties?

Comment: Sorry, im really new into coding and struggling with the naming sometimes.

I meant this: (yeah, properties)
[ { "itemA: "1", "itemB": "2" }, { "itemA": "111", "itemB": "222" } ]

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of React Portal, in below example I'm passing a text props and using de-structuring I'm using the same. (dialog-root is the id where the portal is being appended, in your case it can  be anything for e.g. root etc).

So you can create a store and for that you can go through with mentioned steps [React Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples), and once user click on something you just need to filter out those and pass it to InformationBox which is a Portal.

```
  export default function InformationBox({ text }) {
  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(true);

  const toggleDialog = () => {
    setDialog(!dialog);
  };

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>
      {dialog && (
        <Dialog
          className="custom-dialog-theme no-header-dialog"
          title={' '}
          onClose={toggleDialog}
          width={390}
          height={275}
        >
          <div className="d-flex flex-column align-content-center dialog-content">
            <img src={INFO_ICON} alt="Information" />
            <p>{text}</p>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      )}
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('dialog-root'),
  );
}
```

Comment: @RBN2208 - Please check this out for creating a portal

Comment: Thank you! I will try this method later!